# Thread gets stuck after Console.Read()

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, graphics

I have a program that would read an image if a argument was supplied and it would render it to the screen via a Graphics's object. It is all running on a thread since I have a Console.Read() on the main thread.

```
gw.init();
Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doRenderLoop));
workerThread.Start();
Console.Read();
running = false;
workerThread.Join();
```

And this is the render loop:

```
try
  {
      while (running)
      {
           gw.render();
           Thread.Sleep(1000 / 30);
      }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
       throw;
  }
}
```

And this is gw.render:

```
wg.Clear(bgColor);
wg.Flush();
```

(bgColor is Color.BLACK by the way)

From what the task manager says, my window is fine.
When I look at my window, it would not go in focus and stay in a non-responsive state. [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOChC.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** I tried Eli's post, still no luck. This is the new render loop code:

```
    gw = new GameWindow(800, 600, "Test");
    gw.init();
    gw.render();
    try
    {
        while (running)
        {
            gw.render();
            Thread.Sleep(1000 / 30);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

I still get the same result. And the first 3 lines of the code are not in the main thread.

**EDIT 2:** So I got the threads working, everything displays correctly. But it seems like I still cant focus on the window. Also the wait time was too little so it rendered way to fast.

Comment: Render the window 30 times until a key is pressed? What is the base type of GameWindow? What happens in Init()?

Comment: GameWindow was just a simple wrapper to handle all the graphics stuff. Init would create and show the window, and Render would, well render things. My plan was to make it run 30times/s, or 60times/s, wait for input in the console, dispose and exit the program. Also, your post did work, but explained in the edit above, the window for some reason doesn't let me focus on it. So if I have some buttons, they wouldn't work because I cant focus on it.

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. You need to start with a winform project not a console project. This will have Application.Run somewhere to show your window. You can then add a 'System.Windows.Form.Timer' to periodically call your render method. To close the program simply press the 'x' in the window. There is no need for all those threads and certainly not for the console.

Answer (score 1):

What type is gw?
In any case Graphic objects have thread affinity meaning you can only use them in the thread they where initialized.
Move gw creation and initialization to the worker thread and your program should work as expected (probably).

But why use the console at all? A text field for input would make multi-threading unnecessary for this application?

Comment: The thread he's running the Console on is probably the one that's pumping window messages.

Comment: @hoodaticus You're probably right. I'm trying to figure out why he's not getting an exception for invoking in the wrong thread?

Comment: Yes, that's a very good point and why I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: I agree. VS is not giving me any errors nor exceptions and just lets the program run. I'll try creating this on another thread (explained on the answer) and create an edit or say that this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Console.Read blocks the calling thread until it receives input.  Press Enter in the console and it will move.  I often put it at the start of main() when I want the program to wait until I attach my debugger.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @EliAlgranti - so in other words, "no it won't unless we're in the 99.99% of programs that use the main thread to pump messages".

Comment: The message pump must be invoked. In a graphic program the message pump gets to process messages when the current context (an event handler) returns. In a console application the main thread never returns until the program finishes, so the message pump never gets a chance to run.

Comment: In a graphics application the message pump gains control of the main thread when the root control is shown or made visible. From then on all other calls are event handlers running on that thread.

Comment: The message pump gains control when you run it, usually with an Application.Run or a Dispatcher.Run or somesuch.

Comment: Yes, those methods show the main form, but they're not asynchronous. If you called them then Console.Read() would not be called. So I'm assuming they are not called, which is why the OP's program is hung and why pressing Enter won't help, it would just continue and get stuck on workerThread.Join() because gw.Render() is blocking on the worker thread.

Comment: You're right, pressing enter won't help.  He needs a message pump preferably running on his main thread and that thread should be marked STAThread.  I had initially assumed that the message pump was started further down past the code we can see.

Comment: I have the message pump only for debugging purposes, which **is** marked as STAThread. I have console.read blocking the app from rolling over and dying after it has finished initializing and I highly doubt thats the problem.